# Call Select Method on List created using Expression and use a passed Func<> within the Select method

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I simply want to do this:

```
(inputObj ) => (inputObj .Select(objEln=> hubObjectConverter(objEln)));

inputObj ----> List<elnObject> 

hubObjectConverter ----> Func<object,object>
```

Where am I going wrong?

```
var typeElnObjList = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { elnObjectType });
var inputObj = Expression.Parameter(typeElnObjList, "lstElnObj");

var paramSelectMeth = Expression.Parameter(elnObjectType, "objEln");
var convertToObject = Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(hubObjectConverter), paramSelectMeth);
var lambdaSelect = Expression.Lambda(convertToObject, paramSelectMeth);

var convertList = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), 
                                   "Select", 
                                   new[] { elnObjectType, hubObjectType }, 
                                   inputObj, 
                                   lambdaSelect);  <------ I keep getting an error here. Saying Select cannot accept generic type. Where am I going wrong?
```

Comment: "I simply want to do this:" - what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: (inputObj ) => {inputObj .Select(objEln=> hubObjectConverter(objEln))};
This is the expression I want to create using the Expression Tree

Comment: That is not a valid expression though: a lambda is not a true expression if it has curly braces (that makes it a multi-statement lambda, which is semantically identical to a normal method and cannot be represented by an `Expression<>`, and as you have no `return` keyword it's typed as an `Action`/`void`, not a `Func`.

Comment: (inputObj ) => (inputObj .Select(objEln=> hubObjectConverter(objEln)));
Ok what about this?

Comment: Tip: create a local variable typed as expression and then use the debugger's "debug view" for expressions to see how exactly it is constructed. Then use that info to construct it manually. Ie `Expression<Func<T, TResult>> x = inputObj => inputObj.Select(......)` and then mouse over `x` while debugging and find ".debugview"

Comment: `(inputObj ) => (inputObj .Select(objEln=> hubObjectConverter(objEln)));` is also invalid, expressions cannot be put in parenthesis. Are you sure you can't do this in generic-code? Why are you wanting to use `Expression<T>`?

Comment: do you want specific type parameter like (objexttype inputObj,attributetype objEln ) => inputObj .attribute => objEln

Comment: No I think Dai got me right, I want to convert a list of typeA to a list of TypeB.
My trgaedy is TypeA and TypeB are both in the form of types.

The List<TypeA> is coming in the form of object because I get it from doing the below thing

var listObj = property.GetValue(someObject);

Then I should be able to do:



theFuncMyExporessionWillCreate = TheFunctionCreator(funcConvertor)
List<TypeB> newList = theFuncMyExporessionWillCreate(listObj);

Comment: (objexttype inputObj,attributetype objEln ) => inputObj .attribute => objEln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume your question is [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so I won't answer your question at face-value)

If your intent is to allow converting from a `List<TIn>` to a `List<TOut>` by specifying the type of `TOut` at runtime with a `Type` rather than a generic-type parameter then you only need `MakeGenericMethod` and you don't need to use `Expression<>` at all:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IList ConvertList<TSource>( this List<TSource> source, Type destinationType, Func<object,object> hubObjectConverter )
    {
        if( source is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if( destinationType is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destinationType));
        
        //
        
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(ListExtensions)
            .GetMethod( nameof(ConvertListImpl), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic )
            .MakeGenericMethod( typeof(TSource), destinationType );

        Object result = mi.Invoke( obj: null, new Object[] { source, hubObjectConverter } );
        return (IList)result;
    }

    private static List<TOut> ConvertListImpl<TIn,TOut>( List<TIn> source, Func<Object,Object> converter )
    {
        return source
            .Select( item => converter( item ) )
            .Cast<TOut>()
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

(To improve performance, the `MethodInfo` could be cached in a `static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<(TIn,TOut),MethodInfo>` dictionary).

It would be used like so:

```
List<Int32> listOfInt32 = new List<Int32>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

IList listOfString = listOfInt32.ConvertList( destinationType: typeof(String), obj => obj.ToString() );
```

Even though `listOfString` is statically-typed as `IList`, its actual runtime type is `List<String>`.

Comment: My issue: my TSource is basically: objProperty.GetValue(objInstance) --> because this returns object
Which means I cant use Generics at all

Comment: If you don't know what `TSource` is then it's straightforward to modify my code to add an additional `Type sourceType` parameter.

Comment: Thankyou so much. I tweaked a bit with your code and I hv it now. Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 0):

If do know source type ,That is anonymous  type . So convert that to object type

```js
 class Address
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    }

    class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }


     public static List<object> ConvertToListOfObjects<T>(List<T> list)
        {
            return list.ConvertAll<object>(t => t);
        }

    static void Converttotarget()
        {
            User testUser = new User()
            {
                Name = "Paul",
                Address = new Address()
                {
                    Street = "Freeway",
                    Foo = new Foo() { Bar = "Baz" }
                }
            };
            var users = new List<User>();
            users.Add(testUser);

            var objusers = ConvertToListOfObjects(users);

            var testbj = new { name = "test", rol = 1 };
            var objelist = new List<object>();
            objelist.Add(testbj);

            var lst = ConvertToListOfObjects(objelist);
        }
```